# No such filter attribute 'deleted_at' when using Thinking Sphinx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, thinking-sphinx, soft-delete

I am experiencing some issues with Thinking Sphinx not allowing me to search by the `deleted_at` column in my database.

Essentially, I would like to get a list of all users, active users and deleted users, then be able to undelete certain users defined by the admin. Unfortunately, I can't even list the deleted users when using Thinking Sphinx.  When I do a regular search for all users where 'deleted_at IS NOT NULL', I can get the users.

I can do any other field in my index just fine, but not `deleted_at`. Each time, I get this:

```
ERROR -- : index user_core: no such filter attribute 'deleted_at' (ThinkingSphinx::SphinxError)
```

This is my index file:

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :user, :with => :active_record, :delta => true do
  indexes first_name,     :sortable => true
  indexes last_name,      :sortable => true
  indexes email,          :sortable => true
  indexes phone,          :sortable => true
  has deleted_at,         :as => :deleted
  has id,                 :as => :user_id
  has roles(:id),         :as => :role_ids
  set_property :delta =>  true
end
```

And my query:

```
params[:with][:deleted_at] = 0

@results = User.search :conditions => params[:conditions], :with => params[:with], 
:order => params[:sort] + ' ' + params[:sort_mode], :page => params[:page], 
:per_page => params[:per_page], :star => true
```

NOTE: Even if I do just `@results = User.search`, I still get a list of only all active users where `deleted_at` is null. I do not seem to be able to get all users when using Thinking Sphinx.

Comment: Don't know exactly how ThinkingSphing works, but didn't you name `deleted_at` as `deleted` in the index?
So instead of `params[:with][:deleted_at] = 0` you need `params[:with][:deleted] = 0`

Comment: I have tried both, in either case, I still get an error that there is 'no such filter attribute'.

Comment: Did you run `rake ts:rebuild` after adding that attribute to your index?

Comment: Yes. I have with no changes.